# Who killed Ra's Al Ghul first, Batman or Arrow?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, arrow, batman-begins

In *Arrow*, Ra's Al Ghul is killed by Arrow, whereas in *Batman Begins* Ra's is killed by Bruce Wayne. How can he be killed more than once and who killed Ra's Al Ghul first, Batman or Arrow? Is Malcom Merlyn from *Arrow* the Ra's Al Ghul killed by Batman in *Batman Begins*?

Comment: Arrow and dark night trilogy is not canon to each other. Both Ra's Al Ghul belong to different universe and there is no Merlyn or Arrow in dark night trilogy and neither did batman exists in arrow universe .

Comment: But I they have partnered up according to the link [link](batman.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Arrow)

Comment: Every DC superhero have partnered up in comics, that doesn't make Arrow and dark night trilogy canon.

Comment: Do you know smallville have superman and green arrow too but that doesn't make smallville canon to man of steel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ra's al Ghul is a Batman villain created in 1971. He has spanned multiple titles, and media. He's been killed, and resurrected multiple times (Lazarus Pit or otherwise). The Ra's al Ghul in the Nolan Batman Trilogy, like in the comics, is a person, ***NOT a title/mantle***. The Ra's al Ghul in Arrow is simply the title of the leader of the League of Assasins. **Neither universe overlaps, so neither *"killed"* him first.** There is no connection between them.

*Interestingly enough* [Liam Neeson was offered the role for Ra's in the Arrow, but couldn't, as "Taken 3" was being filmed](http://www.ign.com/articles/2014/10/09/liam-neeson-was-offered-the-role-of-ras-al-ghul-in-arrow):

> but the Oscar-winning actor had to pass because he didn't have the time for The CW series. Mark Pedowitz, president of The CW, told BuzzFeed that the network reached out to Neeson, who played Ra's al Ghul in Christopher Nolan's Dark Knight trilogy. “We never thought he would,” said Pedowitz. “We quickly went to him, just on the off-chance that he had the time to do it.”

Comment: If Liam Neeson had been cast, it would have created more confusion :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you watch the crossover episode from Supergirl Season 1, which is The Flash come and said he come from another world. You can watch The Flash and listen the explanation by Cisco. Supergirl, Superman and Batman live in one world when The Flash, Green Arrow and Merlyn live in another world. The same earth in the different world. Both of that world had their own Ra's. For DC's superhero that don't have a superpower or supersuit (like ATOM), killing Ra's is a last proven to use "super" term.

Comment: I assume that why the producer put The Flash and Green Arrow in the same world, but not in Superman & Batman world, to ensure that The Flash, as the only superhero that can go to another world, can help Green Arrow to join the Justice League in Superman & Batman's world without losing Ra's killing incident. Green Arrow get his own Ra's and so Batman. And we know that J'onn J'onzz, Wonder Women and Aquaman, the other members of JL, have lived in Superman & Batman's world. So they don't need The Flash.

Comment: There is no evidence that Super girl earth "3" is the same as Batman Begins, but otherwise this is an okay answer